# Error with jQuery 1.7.2, nested_form, and simple_form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, simple-form

I'm getting "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object Object]_fields_blueprint" when clicking the link_to_add link in my nested form.

**form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for(@post, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :content %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :news_photos do |p| %>
      <%= p.input :image %>
      <%= p.input :caption %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.link_to_add "Add Photo", :news_photos %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :news_photos, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :news_photos, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**news_photo.rb**

```
class NewsPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => {:featured => "299x185>", :main => "631x298>", :thumb => "104x106>"}, :default_url => "/images/empty.png"
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you include nested_form via the assets pipeline [directly] after JQuery ? `//=require jquery //= require jquery_nested_form`

Comment: Im using rails 3.0.3 so no assets pipeline, but I do have jQuery loading before the nested_form js

Comment: My guess is that's related to the JQuery 1.7.2; try to use 1.9.1

Comment: That works actually, but only if I remove tinyMCE, otherwise I get a no method 'replace' error.

Comment: Well ... you've got a dependency conflict; I suggest you fallback to JQuery 1.6.4 in this case (or try jQ2 ?)
Where does it throw the `no method` error ?

Comment: The "no method replace" error would occur when I clicked the link_to_add link when I had tinymce enabled on the page.  I had been using a tinymce gem, but I've switched to use the JS from tinymce.com and now everything seems to work.

Comment: I suspect this is a legacy issue concerning Rails form helpers, jquery, and sizzle.js. An invalid selector containing characters produced by the rails form helpers (or those produced by simple_form) causes this error in sizzle.js. I am currently experiencing the same issue and I havent found a good working solution or Id post it below :).